# Convert .xlsx to .pdf

Tags: raspbian, python-2.x

I'm looking for a python module to convert a .xlsx excel file to .pdf. My excel file will have formatted cells and embedded images. Does any one have any recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

I used the imagemagick module. I originally downloaded it to convert jpg the pdf. Just on a whim I tried it.

```
os.system('sudo convert file_name.xlsx file_name.pdf')
```

It will kick a few errors in the shell, and creates a folder for it name "_dername", not in the directory I specified, and give it a weird name that starts with "magick-", followed by some random characters. But it does work. In my code, I then use the os module again to move it a rename it.

```
os.system('sudo mv /home/pi/_dername/magick-*.pdf new_name.pdf')
```

This is how I got it going. Feels like the long way to do it, but hey, it work! :)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use [Aspose.Cells Cloud SDK](https://products.aspose.cloud/cells/python) to convert XLSX to PDF.
Have a look on short [example](https://docs.aspose.cloud/display/cellscloud/Convert+Excel+Workbook+to+Different+File+Formats):

```
#set file name
filename = "input.xls"
outputfilename = "output.pdf"

#upload file to aspose cloud storage
storageApi.PutCreate(Path=filename)

#convert file to pdf
response = cellsApi.PostDocumentSaveAs(name=filename, body=body, newfilename=outputfilename)
destfilename = response.SaveResult.DestDocument.Href

#download converted file from storage server
response = storageApi.GetDownload(Path=destfilename)
```

Hope it helps. Otherwise, feel free to ask me.

**Note**: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful. Try this code..........

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from PDFWriter import PDFWriter
workbook = load_workbook('fruits2.xlsx', guess_types=True, data_only=True)
worksheet = workbook.active
pw = PDFWriter('fruits2.pdf')
pw.setFont('Courier', 12)
pw.setHeader('XLSXtoPDF.py - convert XLSX data to PDF')
pw.setFooter('Generated using openpyxl and xtopdf')
ws_range = worksheet.iter_rows('A1:H13')
for row in ws_range:
            s = ''
            for cell in row:
                   if cell.value is None:
                              s += ' ' * 11
                   else:
                              s += str(cell.value).rjust(10) + ' '
            pw.writeLine(s)
pw.savePage()
pw.close()
```

Comment: https://jugad2.blogspot.in/2015/11/convert-xlsx-to-pdf-with-python-and.html

Comment: I appreciate the answer. I am having difficulty down loading PDFWriter to my RPi. Also, I did read somewhere that the xtopdf module does not convert the formatted cells and images.